# Scala: Removing nodes from XML at different levels

Tags: xml, scala

My xml looks like this: (it's a `NodeSeq`)

```
<first>...</first>
<second>...</second>
<third>
    <foo>
        <keepattr> ... </keepattr>
        <otherattr1> ... </otherattr1>
    </foo>
    <otherattr2> ... </otherattr2>
</third>
```

I need to keep `<first>`, remove `<second>` and anything inside it, and only keep `<keepattr>` inside `<third>`, while keeping the data architecture (keeping the foo tag)

how can I do that in Scala?

I tried this but I'm stuck for going one level down

```
val removeJunk = new RewriteRule {
  override def transform(node: Node): NodeSeq = node match {
    case e: Elem => e.label match {
      case "second" => NodeSeq.Empty
      case "third" => //?
    }
    case o => o

  }
}
```

And I am possibly interested in going couple levels down in the scheme

Edit: I am looking to keep data while not compromising the data model

```
<third>
    <foo>
      <keepattr> ... </keepattr> 
      <otherattr1> ... </otherattr1>
    </foo>
    <otherattr2> ... </otherattr2>
</third>
```

should become

```
<third>
    <foo>
      <keepattr> ... </keepattr> 
    </foo>
</third>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of `filterNot` and a `RewriteRule`. This might be inefficient due to the use of the `\\` operator at every step, but I can't think of any other solution right now:

```
val input: NodeBuffer = <first>foo</first>
  <second>remove me</second>
  <third>
    <foo>
      <keepattr>meh</keepattr>
      <otherattr1>bar</otherattr1>
    </foo>
    <otherattr2>quux</otherattr2>
  </third>

val extractKeepAttr = new RewriteRule {
  override def transform(node: Node): NodeSeq = node match {
    case e: Elem => e.label match {
      case "keepattr" => e
      case _ if (e \\ "keepattr").nonEmpty => 
        e copy (child = e.child.filter(c => (c \\ "keepattr").nonEmpty) flatMap transform)
      case _ => e
    }
  }
}

// returns <first>foo</first>, <third><foo><keepattr>meh</keepattr></foo></third>
val updatedXml = input.filterNot(_.label == "second").transform(extractKeepAttr)
```

**EDIT**: updated answer

Comment: will this keep the architecture of my xml in case of deep nesting, or will it bring up the attribute?

Comment: It will extract the matched descendant, i.e. for the nested example above with the `foo` element you will get `<third><keepattr>...</keepattr></third>`.

Comment: I'm going to sound picky but look at this output, it doesn't trim away otherattr1: val input = <first>a</first>
      <second>a</second>
      <third>
        <foo>
          <keepattr> a </keepattr>
          <otherattr1> a </otherattr1>
        </foo>
        <otherattr2> a </otherattr2>
      </third>;

    val output = input.filterNot(_.label == "second").transform(extractKeepAttr)

    println(output.toString)

ArrayBuffer(<first>a</first>, <third><foo>
          <keepattr> a </keepattr>
          <otherattr1> a </otherattr1>
        </foo></third>)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I missed that you updated the question once more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68874/discussion-between-stephane-and-edi).

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out another answer that removes a lot of the complexity but is not that pretty... Extract all the information you need out of the XML, store it in vals, and reconstruct the XML manually if you know the structure in advance.